# Proving the limit $\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{2}}{x+2}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{6}$ using the epsilon-delta definition.

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Prove $\lim_{x \to -2} \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{2}}{x+2}=\frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{6}$.

Solution Attempt:

$\left| f(x) - L \right| < \epsilon$

$\left|f(x)-L \right|=\left| \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{2}}{x+2} - \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}}{6} \right|$

$=\left| \frac{6\left( \sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{2}\right)-\sqrt[3]{2} (x+2)}{6(x+2)} \right|$

$=\left| \frac{6\sqrt[3]{x}+4\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{2}x}{6(x+2)}\right|$

$=\frac{1}{6}\left| \frac{6\sqrt[3]{x}+4\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{2}x}{x+2}\right|$

$\left| \frac{6\sqrt[3]{x}+4\sqrt[3]{2}-\sqrt[3]{2}x}{x+2}\right|<6\epsilon$

I am now stuck at this part of the solution. Can someone assist me?

Comment: Note that $x+2=(\sqrt[3]{x})^3+(\sqrt[3]{2})^3$ and $y^3+z^3=(y+z)(y^2-yz+z^2)$.

Comment: Not only is John Omielan's comment the key to attacking the problem, but in addition (a) The entire problem becomes trivial once you focus on his comment. (b) Also, I surmise that the intent of the problem composer, and the whole point of the problem is to force the problem solver to find the insight inherent in John Omielan's comment.

Comment: 남성 심장 (male heart), please read my answer and tell me if it is useful for you.

Answer (score 2):

For any $\,x\in(-4,16)\,\land\,x\neq-2\,$ it results that

$\dfrac16\,\left|\dfrac{6\sqrt[3]x\!+\!4\sqrt[3]2\!-\!\sqrt[3]2\,x}{x+2}\right|=\dfrac16\,\left|\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\left(2\sqrt[3]2\!-\!\sqrt[3]x\right)\!\left(\sqrt[3]x\!+\!\sqrt[3]2\right)^2}{x+2}\right|\!=$

$\!\!\!\!\!\!\!=\!\dfrac16\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\!\left(2\sqrt[3]2\!-\!\sqrt[3]x\right)\!\!\left(\sqrt[3]x\!+\!\sqrt[3]2\right)^2}{\left|x+2\right|}\!<\!\dfrac16\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\!\left(2\sqrt[3]2\!+\!\sqrt[3]4\right)\!\!\left(\sqrt[3]x\!+\!\sqrt[3]2\right)^2}{\left|x+2\right|}\!=$

$=\dfrac16\,\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\!\left(2\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4\right)\!\left(\sqrt[3]x+\sqrt[3]2\right)^2\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{2x}+\sqrt[3]4\right)^2}{\left|x+2\right|\!\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{2x}+\sqrt[3]4\right)^2}=$

$\!\!\!\!\!\!=\dfrac16\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\!\left(2\sqrt[3]2\!+\!\sqrt[3]4\right)\!\left(x\!+\!2\right)^2}{\big|x\!+\!2\big|\,\left[\left(\!\sqrt[3]x\!-\!\frac{\sqrt[3]2}2\right)^2\!\!+\!\frac{3\sqrt[3]4}4\right]^2}=\dfrac16\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\!\left(2\sqrt[3]2\!+\!\sqrt[3]4\right)\big|x\!+\!2\big|}{\left[\left(\!\sqrt[3]x\!-\!\frac{\sqrt[3]2}2\right)^2\!\!+\!\frac{3\sqrt[3]4}4\right]^2}\leqslant$

$\leqslant\dfrac16\,\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\!\left(2\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4\right)\big|x+2\big|}{\left(\frac{3\sqrt[3]4}4\right)^2}=\dfrac16\,\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\!\left(2\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4\right)\big|x+2\big|}{\frac{9\sqrt[3]2}8}<$

$<\dfrac16\,\dfrac{\sqrt[3]2\big(4+2\big)\,\big|x+2\big|}{\frac{9\sqrt[3]2}8}=\dfrac89\,\big|x+2\big|<\big|x+2\big|\,.$

We have proved that

$\dfrac16\,\left|\dfrac{6\sqrt[3]x+4\sqrt[3]2-\sqrt[3]2\,x}{x+2}\right|<\big|x+2\big|\;\,,\;\;\,\forall x\!\in\!(-4,16)\setminus\{-2\}.$

Consequently,

for any $\,\varepsilon>0\,$ there exists $\,\delta=\min\{2,\varepsilon\}>0\,$ such that

$\forall x\!\in\!\big(\!\!-\!2\!-\!\delta,-2\!+\!\delta\big)\!\setminus\!\{-2\}\subsetneq(-4,16)\!\setminus\!\{-2\}\,$ it results that

$\big|f(x)-L\big|=\dfrac16\,\left|\dfrac{6\sqrt[3]x+4\sqrt[3]2-\sqrt[3]2\,x}{x+2}\right|<\big|x+2\big|<\delta\leqslant\varepsilon\,.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x = y^3$ is bijection on $\mathbb{R}$, applying a change of variable makes it much easier
$$
\lim_{x\to -2}\frac{\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{2}}{x + 2}\\
\lim_{y\to -\sqrt[3]{2}}\frac{1}{y^2 - \sqrt[3] 2y + 2^{2\over3}}
$$

Apparently $\lim_{y\to -\sqrt[3]{2}}{y^2 - \sqrt[3] 2y + 2^{2\over3}}\ne 0$, you could apply $\epsilon-\delta$ definition on this and trace back to original limit.